# How do I extract the text content of an article site with Python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, text, extract, urllib

I've tried the following:

```
import urllib

link = 'https://automatetheboringstuff.com/chapter7/'
f = urllib.request.urlopen(link)
myfile = f.read()
print(myfile)
```

But that just seems to return the page's source rather than the text content.

Comment: You need `BeautifulSoup` for that

Comment: Is that correct `urllib.request.urlopen(link)` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only want to get chapter text, beautiful soup is your choice, I think.

In your case:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

res = requests.get('https://automatetheboringstuff.com/chapter7/')
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text, 'html.parser')
print(soup.find('div', { "class" : "book" }).text)
```